# isc-dhcp-server and pihole

Tags: docker, isc-dhcpd, pi-hole

I have two single board computers in my local network (Pine64 and nanoPI), which I use for various purposes.

The latest thing I wanted to do with them is to have failover DHCP and DNS for my local network on both of them. I configured failover DHCP and one of them was not starting until I didn't stop/delete the pihole docker image. It was reporting `Can't bind to dhcp address: Address already in use`. When docker was stopped ISC-DHCP-SERVER is starting just fine. Now, when DHCP server is running the docker reports `bind: address already in use` and does not start. The other computer which has ordinary DNS server installed (no docker and pihole) works fine.

I configured my own DNS with similar capabilities as pihole (block advertisements) on another server. However, I wanted to try pihole, since it has nice user interface.

I think the problem is that pihole includes a DHCP server, too (https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/how-do-i-use-pi-holes-built-in-dhcp-server-and-why-would-i-want-to/3026). Can I use pihole docker image (without DHCP) and DHCP server on the same computer? How it can be done?

I would rather not use pihole's DHCP, because I have some custom configuration in DHCP server with publishing custom routes via DHCP, DHCP static leases, and failover configuration. I am not sure I can configure all that in pihole's DHCP server, and I am not sure I want to.

Answer (score 1):

If I install pihole directly (https://docs.pi-hole.net/main/basic-install/) and not as a docker image, it detects static IP configured on the computer and it does not mess with DHCP.

So the answer would be, install pihole directly to a supported operating system.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run a DHCP server in a Docker/Container. The reason you are having issues is that the docker container creates it's own bridge network, which is a distinctly different subnet than your primary subnet/lan that your router/network runs on.

You generally would have to pass through or bridge the docker container to the host network.

https://gist.github.com/mikejoh/04978da4d52447ead7bdd045e878587d

I recommend that you use the  --net host flag

https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/homecentr/dhcp

Comment: The reason for issues was the fact that docker occupied ports for DHCP, and ISC-DHCP-SERVER wanted to use the same ports. A direct pihole installation detected running DHCP server and did try to run its own DHCP service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Run Pi-hole in docker, bridge network is fine. You want to map ports 53 for DNS port and whatever port you choose for the Web interface to the pi-hole container.

When running a DHCP server inside of a container, you need to set up a DHCP relay service to forward DHCP requests to the Dockerized DHCP server. Some routers include this service so look there first.

There are also open source DHCP-relay servers, so if you router doesn't have the relay feature, you will need to set one up to do the forwarding.